# What is the correct way of quoting references?

Tags: discussion, faq-content

In the questions or answers, what do we post as references and how do we do it? What are the reliable sources of references?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As references you can post the following (The following list is also in the order of the reliability and deserved priority):

1. Ayaah of the Holy Qur'an
2. Sahih Ahadith
3. Tafseer by Universally trusted mufassireen.
4. Fatwas by Universally trusted Muftis.
5. Other reliable Islamic sources.

All references must be placed in a blockquote. After typing/pasting the reference text, select the text and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> or click the **[image: BlockQuote]** button of the text editor. Your text will be placed in a blockquote.

Format of posting reference quotes is as follows:

1. **Ayaah of the Holy Qur'an:** The translation of the (full or part of) relevant ayah suffixed with the correct Surah name/number, Ayah number and optionally the translation name. Adding arabic text is not always a good idea because many readers might not know how to read it. Instead, a link to a page from an external trusted site that shows this Ayah would help readers verify it.

   Eg.

   > And [mention] when We said to the angels, "Prostrate before Adam"; so they prostrated, except for Iblees. He refused and was arrogant and became of the disbelievers.
   >   [***Qur'an 2:34.***](http://quran.com/2/34) 
   >  **[OR]** 
   >  [***Al-Baqarah : Ayah 34.***](http://quran.com/2/34) 
   > **[OR]**
   >  ***[Surah al-Baqarah : Ayah 34](http://quran.com/2/34) (Translation: Sahih International).***
2. **Sahih Ahadith:** The translation of the (full or part of) relevant hadith suffixed with the correct Collection name (Bukhari, Muslim, Tirmidhi, etc.) followed by the correct volume name/number followed by the correct Book name/number and finally followed by the correct hadith number. Adding arabic text is not always a good idea because many readers might not know how to read it. Instead link to a page from an external trusted site that shows this hadith would help readers verify it.

   Eg.

   > **Narrated Abdullah bin Umar:**
   >   Allah's Messenger ([image]) said, "A Muslim is a brother of another Muslim. So he should neither oppress him nor hand him over to an oppressor. And whoever fulfilled the needs of his brother, Allah will fulfill his needs."
   >   ***[Al-Bukhari : Volume 9 : Book 85 : Hadith 83.](http://sunnah.com/urn/65380)*** 
   >  **[OR]** 
   >   ***[Sahih Al-Bukhari : Book of Ikraah (compulsion) : Hadith 83.](http://sunnah.com/urn/65380)***
3. **Fatwas & Tafseer:** BlockQuote the necessary text and provide the link to a webpage of a trusted website that hosts the fatwa.

Comment: The second point mentions adding "correct" volume/book/hadith numbers, but this is unclear; there may be various equally-valid numbering schemes between different publications of the same collection (following the link in your example, for example, also offers Book 89 : Hadith 7037 as a reference number).

Comment: @goldPseudo, Can you lead me to the list of number schemes? I'll try and update my answer suitably. Jazaakallah...

Comment: I don't know that there's an actual *list* anywhere; [this answer](http://islam.stackexchange.com/a/2441/22) describes differences between the prominent numbering systems used for Sahih Bukhari alone, but different compilations use different systems (and each have their own potential points of confusion).