# Should users reveal their real Identity?

Tags: feature-request, etiquette, design

Islamic Sciences place a great deal of importance of Identity and Character moral values of a Muslim narrator who replies to Islamic question. This site seems to ensure a good scope for any geek who gives beautiful looking answers with 'n' references and a closely knit nexus of like minded geeks.
But the traditional Islamic scholars put a great deal of emphasis on the identity and life of the user. Agreed it is not possible to know the life of the narrator here but it is definitely possible to enforce narrators to reveal their real VERIFIABLE identity.

There should be template form decided that would require each user to reveal information like Education, Religion\ Sect , fathers name , Short Biography etc
Although all of the above can be faked but this can be made verifiable by linking it to any online presence of the user like Home university profile, Employer login etc.
Critical information to be available only to the moderators.

Comment: Hello -- I think the type of analysis that you're looking for (and personalization) might be beyond the scope of this site. The user tachyons, in the answer below, includes other reasons why anonymity is important. Also, bear in mind: not all users on the site are Muslims. Many are people who have a strong interest in the Islamic faith (or who wish to understand its relationship to the other Abhrahamic faiths better) and thus wouldn't meet the criteria you've outlined.

Answer (score 7):

This is not a fatwa website or islamic website, This is just a stackexchange website for question answer related to islam. If you want fatwa on a topic you should contact scholor in your area. Here we are just community members and many users have privacy concerns while posting personal info

Comment: yes, but you have entered into the business of fatwa. New users may take a long time to understand the SE culture

Answer (score 3):

Establishing a *verifiable* identity on the internet in general is hardly a trivial matter.  Even if a system was set up on this site, it would likely require new users to jump through so many hoops that most of them would be deterred from even joining the site.  Given that a community-driven site needs to build an actual community to do the driving, deterring new users thus is probably against our best interests.

As I tried to lay out in a different meta post ([How do I write a good answer to a question?](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/a/610/22)), I feel that the best way around this issue is not to clearly establish the identity of all users, rather it is better to assume that *all users on the site have no authority*.  We are not scholars, we are peers.  Even if [the Grand Mufti of Saudia Arabia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abdul-Azeez_ibn_Abdullaah_Aal_ash-Shaikh) himself were to log in and start answering questions, he would still be expected to lay out his (verifiable) evidences in full.

This way, any answer has the potential of being equally useful, regardless of if it comes from a random schmoe on the street or from an established Islamic authority.

We are a question and answer site.  Just because some of these answers may involve *fatawa* doesn't automatically make us a *fatwa* site.  The difference may be subtle, but it *is* important.

In short (and in other words): **If any answer is written in such a way that verifying the posters identity is important, it's probably just a bad answer**.  It may need to be downvoted, editted, flagged or whatever, but it would not be a good fit for the site as is.

Answer (score 1):

Users are free to use their real identity, which may come with their scholarly reputation (if they have any).  This may be beneficial to a scholar.  Users are also free not to use their real identity.

I come from the original MathOverflow, and when it was started there was a push for contributors to use their real names.  (See e.g. [Anonymity Policy](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/2574/48278) and various linked posts.)  I've used my real name since then.  My family, friends, work colleagues, etc., can all see what I write here, so I'm careful with what I say.

Using one's real name:

1. makes you more accountable for your actions, and less willing to [engage in childish behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_disinhibition_effect);
2. makes you put more effort into your posts, as there's more at stake; and
3. it humanizes you, the reader knows that I am an actual person.

So there's some advantages to using your real name.

There's also some disadvantages, such as privacy (I get some surprise emails from time to time).