# What makes a good [fatwa-explanation] question?

Tags: discussion

I just read a fatwa, but there's something about it that I don't understand. This totally looks like a job for the [fatwa-explanation](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fatwa-explanation) tag, but how should I phrase my question?

Answer (score 2):

In order to ensure that such a question attracts [actual *useful* answers](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/598/22), rather than [argument and debate](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1255/22), it is important that it be presented as objectively as possible.  As such, the following guidelines are recommended:

### 1. Identify the fatwa

This is probably the most important step: The question needs to be based on an *existing* fatwa given by an authority under an identifiable methodology. If the question is about a common doctrinal/cultural understanding (e.g. if your question is "Everybody tells me that…" rather than "This particular scholar says that…"), it is too vague to be a [fatwa-explanation](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fatwa-explanation) (but it could end up as a good [islamic-basis](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/islamic-basis) question instead)

**1a. What counts as an "authority under an identifiable methodology"?**

What is or is not considered authoritative can be highly subjective, but for the purposes of this meta post a fatwa can be considered "given by an authority under an identifiable methodology" if it…

- …is clearly identified with an established *madh'hab*
- …is written by a scholar with a large enough corpus of fatawa (i.e. a fatwa site or published work) that their methodology can reasonably be 
  interpreted

If, however, that fatwa comes from a forum or blog post from a relative unknown, it probably does not count as "authoritative".

What is important is that the *foundations* for the fatwa are understood (or can reasonably be *expected* to be understood), and that the person *providing* the fatwa understood (or can reasonably be *expected* to have understood) those foundations when presenting his own fatwa.

### 2. Identify the perspective

It is essential that such a question is scoped to the exact perspective of the fatwa itself, be this perspective a particular *sect*, a particular *madh'hab*, or even a particular *scholar*. If you're interested in an *explanation* of the fatwa, it is important that the fundamental methodology of the fatwa itself is [presumed *valid*](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/275/why-sectarianism-is-ruining-your-site); outside perspectives which reject those foundations are more likely to devolve into arguments *about* those foundations than any actual useful *explanation* of the end result.

### 3. Explain the confusion

Just saying you don't understand the fatwa doesn't really *say* anything. *What* exactly don't you understand? Does it use complex grammar and vocabulary that you're having trouble parsing? Does it apparently contradict strong evidences? The more details you provide, the easier it is for others to resolve the issue.