# At what point will Islam.se grow out of the beta stage?

Tags: discussion, beta

Reading other discussion on area51 and other sites meta(https://bicycles.meta.stackexchange.com/a/317), I got to know that all the 5 bullet points need not be in green status for being eligible for a site to be launced.

Any info on this?

The below stats look good to me in comparision of other launched websites. It's >4 years

[image: Islam.SE]

Comment: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/when-will-my-site-graduate/

Answer (score 4):

Ignore those numbers; they're supposed to give rough guidelines about when a site is considered viable, but they're based on predictions that were made way back in the early days of Area 51 before anybody really *knew* what it took to make a site work.

If you want some better rough numbers to gauge our ability to graduate, I'd suggest just looking at the following:

- Are we consistently averaging [10 or more questions a day](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/257614/132874)?
- Are these questions consistently getting *useful* answers?

Right now, I'd say that both of those answers are "No". There's been very little growth in our average questions-per-day since we started; even now, in the middle of Ramadan (our busiest time), we're barely reaching the mark:

[image]

And as for *useful* answers, that's far more speculative: What exactly constitutes a "useful" answer? I've expressed my own opinion on that [in the past](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/a/610/22), and quite frankly a *lot* of the answers I see don't really meet the criteria for what I would consider "useful"; there are *far* too many posts written by users with barely any grasp of the how the Islamic sciences work or even basic critical evaluation (or even the English language, let's be honest here).

Most of the answers here are barely any better than what you can already get from any number of Islamic fora, or shallow regurgitations of easily-found third-party articles; I'm sure you know how much of a mess *those* already are. Islam Stack Exchange is trying to *improve* on what's already out there, not just bring the same mess over to a new venue.

I've said it any number of times before, and I'll keep saying it: What we need to graduate is *experts*, who not only have the ability to answer existing questions, but are also able to ask *new and interesting* questions that will attract *other* experts. There a *reason* most Islamic fora out there don't tend to attract a lot of actual *expert* participation, and if the site keeps encouraging low-quality questions, all it'll attract are low-quality users who keep providing low-quality answers.

And that, I can definitely say, is *not* the path to graduation.

Comment: **<comments deleted>** Comments are expected to stay focussed on the topic of discussion and the post they're attached to, not to argue about tangential issues.

Comment: I've been re-reading and re-thinking your answer ever since you posted it. I've wondered what makes christianity.SE different. I think it has something to do with the approach to doctrine. In Christianity, what you believe is more important than anything else. So they spend a lot of time masticating minutia, which attracts people who like to specialize and intellectualize. It seems to me that Islam is not nearly so doctrine-oriented. I see arguments over Abu Bakr and Ali, but none of the doctrinal hair-splitting that causes Christians to burn each other at the stake.

Comment: The first giant split in Christianity was over intellectual matters. Islam's was a much more practical matter. In Christianity, what you do is a sign of your salvation, but not the means of salvation. Christians can be bad and still be saved. My (limited) understanding of Islam is that you *must* be good. So Christians don't have to be as pragmatic? But I've barely even scratched the surface of Islam, so perhaps I'm totally missing something huge. And maybe this is all painfully obvious to everyone and/or not useful in any way. Just some thoughts.