# Was stack exchange built to answer ahl al sunnah wal jamaa'ah muslims' questions?

Tags: discussion, sunnah

i know there many sects in islam and only one of them will go to jannah as the prophet said صلى الله عليه وسلم , so is this stack exchange for everyone to post questions and have them answered, for example the shia, or just ahl al sunnah wal jamaa'ah? as far as i am concerned most the answers were sunnah based with the understanding of the righteous salaf, although i sadly saw people quoting one hadith and doing fatwa with it, even though there were other ahadith that would go exactly against it.

Comment: None does fatwa here. We quote and explain and post possible solutions!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why Sectarianism is Ruining Your Site](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/275/why-sectarianism-is-ruining-your-site)

Comment: About fatwa: [It is also important to note that this is not a fatwa site](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1815/giving-help-or-fatwa-or-advice-or-what)

Answer (score 3):

***No it is not,*** It is a community built site which includes Muslims and non-Muslims as well

> Islam Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for experts in Islam, students of knowledge, and those interested in Islam on an academic level. It's built and run by you as part of the Stack Exchange network of Q&A sites. With your help, we're working together to build a library of detailed answers to every question about Islam on an academic level. from [Tour](https://islam.stackexchange.com/tour)

And you cannot take this as proof to consider other sects as wrong, each believes that their sect is righteous. Answers here cannot be taken as authentic proof.

And answers which are opinionated and from non-authentic sources are not welcomed here.

Otherwise, we need to add as many tags as sects so each will point to one sect of Islam.

Comment: I did not get a satisfactory answer, this is not fit to be even a comment, please answer the point.

Comment: okay, may I know what you are expecting edited my answer though

Comment: @SalmaanAl-Faaris if you want a satisfactory answer you should write a focused and clear question!